# Thymeleaf - Suggested approach when tabular data table returns zero records (empty list)?

Tags: thymeleaf

Given:

```
<table id="identification-data" class="pure-table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
   <th>DOB</th>
   <th>Gender</th>
 <tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr th:each="row : ${identificationData}">
   <td th:text="${row['Name']}">Brian Smith</td>
   <td th:text="${#calendars.format(row['Date of Birth'], 'MM/dd/yyyy')}">10/11/1971</td>
   <td th:text="${row['Gender']}">Male</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

If the collection ${identificationData} is empty - is there a ***thymeleafy*** way to show a message like "no data found"?

I could do something on the controller side like:

```
if (identificationData.isEmpty()){
    model.addAttribute("identificationDataNotFound", Boolean.TRUE);
}
model.addAttribute("identificationData", identificationData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most "thymeleafy" way that I can think of is to conditionally render a `<tbody>` containing the "No data found" message if the list is empty. You can use the utility object `#lists` to check if the list is empty in the UI (saving you one more boolean model attribute)

```
<tbody th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(identificationData)}">
    <tr th:each="row : ${identificationData}">
        ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(identificationData)}">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">No Data found</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```